# Rails SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I am testing my app ( Rails 5) with rspec capybara and factory girl I have the following error...
I am not sure what's happening... I am very new with rspec I hope you could help me :) thank you

```
Randomized with seed 41137

An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

SystemStackError:
  stack level too deep
```

You will find my code below:

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    name {Faker::Friends.character}
    total_price 50
    participant
  end

  factory :participant do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    salary 900
    event
  end
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :participants, inverse_of: :event
  validates :participants, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
  validates :total_price, presence: true


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  def total_salary
    all_salary = []
    participants.each do |participant|
      all_salary << participant.salary
    end
    return @total_salary = all_salary.inject(0,:+)
  end
end
```

event_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Event do
  it { should have_many(:participants) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:participants) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:total_price) }

  describe "#total_salary" do
    it "should return the total salary of the participants" do
      partcipant_1 = create(:participant, salary: 2000)
      partcipant_2 = create(:participant, salary: 3000)

      expect(partcipant_1.salary + partcipant_2.salary).to eq(5000)
    end
  end
end
```

### edit

In my participant model I had to add `optional: true`
`belongs_to :event, option: true`

so fabriciofreitag suggestion works well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at your factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    name {Faker::Friends.character}
    total_price 50
    participant
  end
  factory :participant do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    salary 900
    event
  end
end
```

In this scenario, the creation of event will create a participant, that will create an event, that will create a participant. and so on, in an infinite loop (stack level too deep).

Perhaps you could change it to something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    name {Faker::Friends.character}
    total_price 50
    participants { create_list(:participant, 3, event: self) }
  end
  factory :participant do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    salary 900
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your suggestion unfortunately I have this error: 
`.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb:42:in add_attribute': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Apologies, I updated the post with the correction.@Liwis

Comment: Hello thanks :)
I still have error :(

`Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * event - Validation failed: Event must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
  * participant - Validation failed: Event must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)`

Comment: @Liwis apologies, it's hard to test where I am right now, but this last edition should solve it. You didn't post the participant model, so I didn't know it was requiring Event.

Comment: @Liwis, Don't just copy/paste the errors you're getting. Put in some effort to understand them and if you don't then ask about that. Seems you're expecting Fabricio to write your code for you.

Comment: This actually work , the error was in my model I had to add  `optional: true` in my belongs_to :event  @Mischa